# Missing folders in windows network share mounted using samba

Tags: networking, mount, windows, samba, cifs

I'm a new ubuntu user and i'm having big trouble mounting a windows network share using samba and cifs.

I installed cifs-utils then mounted using:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=**** //WIN_PC/WIN_SHARE/ /mnt/samba/WIN_SHARE
```

This seems to work nicely, with the exception that some folders do not appear at the mount point.
Also the root user cannot see them, which makes me think it has nothing to do with chown etc.
I did `chown -R user:user` on the mount point.

Now the funny thing is: If i don't mount the network share and instead open it as `smb://WIN_PC/WIN_SHARE/` by just clicking through the network using the file browser, then I can see the entire content without problems. (I still have to enter credentials first, and i am using the same credentials.)

So I don't think this has something to do with the windows share config but with the samba config on my ubuntu machine.

Could anyone please help me? I already tried a lot of things and getting very frustrated. Sorry if I am too stupid ;)

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: After you open it by clicking it through the network, run `mount | grep WIN_SHARE` and see all the permissions it might have mounted it with.  Then do the same thing with your normal share and compare the two.

Comment: Does it help if you mount with `mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=****,uid=yourlinuxusername,gid=users //WIN_PC/WIN_SHARE/ /mnt/samba/WIN_SHARE`

Comment: @Terrance: if i opened it by clicking through the network, then 'mount | grep WIN_SHARE' does not produce an output. I think it is not mounted.

Comment: @Bruni: Changing the command this way does not make a difference :(

Comment: I was able to find the mount output that is generated by clicking on the network share:
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)

The manual mount looks like this:
//WIN_PC/WIN_SHARE/ on /mnt/samba/WIN_PC/WIN_SHARE type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=default,cache=strict,username=user,domain=,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=100,forcegid,addr=192.168.100.76,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)

Comment: It appears that a heap of options are different. Dont really know what i should change first and how. Changing uid and gid doesnt help.

Comment: Can you try one more manual mount command here?  I was thinking of `mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=*****,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm /WIN_PC/WIN_SHARE/ /mnt/samba/WIN_SHARE`  The only reason I am asking this is this is the way that I have my `fstab` at home configured and I see every folder and file of my mount.

Comment: I tried, but this also does not show the folders ...
But the very strange thing is: The folders are there, I can open them manually using 'cd foldername' !
But they are never listed, not in console, not in file browser, not even with 'll -a'.
I can live with this for now, i can access my stuff ... but its extremely strange and I would very much like to understand this

Comment: @NA_ Are there any symbolic links in the share?  I was seeing on some old posts somewhere where the symbolic links were not showing up properly in the app.

Comment: Not an expert ... but i think symbolic links are a linux thing. These share folders are on a windows machine and the folders are no links of any kind ... They are just located there.

Comment: In Windows a symbolic link is called a shortcut.  But it looks as though it was the vers= which you might actually not want to use SMBv1, as it has a major vulnerability see:  https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity/2017/03/16/Microsoft-SMBv1-Vulnerability  You might want to use SMBv2 or SMBv3 see:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and

Comment: Thanks for your help Terrance. I've decided to switch back to the current version, even though the folders are only listed with 1.0.
I've made some links to the important folders, so it works out for me. Just hope this problem will be fixed sometime ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a long shot because I do not know what version of the kernel you are using but change your mount command or any of the other ones offered here to include the option **vers=1.0**

For example:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=****,vers=1.0 //WIN_PC/WIN_SHARE/ /mnt/samba/WIN_SHARE
```

There is a bug report that describes your situation: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1572132

The reason why nautilus / gvfs works is because by default the samba client uses smb1 ( the equivalent of vers=1.0 ) whereas cifs since Linux kernel 4.13 uses smb3 by default.

**EDIT**: *I should note that with Ubuntu 18.04 the samba client / nautilus / gvfs can go beyond smb1 to smb3 in which case neither method would have worked without changing some configuration.*